# My app is in compatible in 2.3.3,how make it compatible

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am developing an application which is compatible with versions 2.3.3 and above

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10"
    android:maxSdkVersion="17"/>

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>
```

and during my development time it was working on my 2.3.6 Samsung galaxy device.

However, after putting my application in the Play store it shows that it is not compatible with my device. Why is that?

Comment: Please add the whole manifest code related to the uses-features, screens supported etc..

Comment: very strange behaviour

Comment: any solutions is there?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target):

> **android:targetSdkVersion**
>
> An integer designating the API Level that the
>   application targets. If not set, the default value equals that given
>   to minSdkVersion. This attribute informs the system that you have
>   tested against the target version and the system should not enable any
>   compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility
>   with the target version. The application is still able to run on older
>   versions (down to minSdkVersion).
>
> As Android evolves with each new version, some behaviors and even
>   appearances might change. However, if the API level of the platform is
>   higher than the version declared by your app's targetSdkVersion, the
>   system may enable compatibility behaviors to ensure that your app
>   continues to work the way you expect. You can disable such
>   compatibility behaviors by specifying targetSdkVersion to match the
>   API level of the platform on which it's running. For example, setting
>   this value to "11" or higher allows the system to apply a new default
>   theme (Holo) to your app when running on Android 3.0 or higher and
>   also disables screen compatibility mode when running on larger screens
>   (because support for API level 11 implicitly supports larger screens).
>
> There are many compatibility behaviors that the system may enable
>   based on the value you set for this attribute. Several of these
>   behaviors are described by the corresponding platform versions in the
>   Build.VERSION_CODES reference.
>
> **To maintain your application along with each Android release, you should increase the value of this attribute to match the latest API
>   level, then thoroughly test your application on the corresponding
>   platform version. Introduced in: API Level 4**

Try increasing the targetSDK attribute to "17" for example.